Custom Routes in NextJS to support countries and languages
My site paths are like -

https://www.example.com/us/en/products
https://www.example.com/us/es/products
https://www.example.com/us/en/categories
https://www.example.com/us/es/categories

or -
https://www.example.com/[countryCode]/[languageCode]/products
Though libraries like - next-intl provides a way to deal with languages only but not if it has some previous country code attached to it.
Let me know any pointer on this.

Finally it works. App Router setup without i18n routing
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router/without-i18n-routing
middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {   
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const locale = url.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean)[1];
  requestHeaders.set('locale', locale);

  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });

  return response;
}

i18n/request.ts:
import { getRequestConfig } from 'next-intl/server';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export default getRequestConfig(async () => {
  // Provide a static locale, fetch a user setting,
  // read from `cookies()`, `headers()`, etc.

  const locales = ['en', 'de'];
  const headersList = headers();
  const l = headersList.get('locale') || '';
  
  let locale = 'en';
  if (locales.includes(l)) {
    locale = l;
  }

  return {
    locale,
    messages: (await import(`../messages/${locale}.json`)).default,
  };
});

[code]/[locale]/page.tsx
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

export default function HomePage() {
  const t = useTranslations('HomePage');

  return <h1>{t('title')}</h1>;
}

messages/de.json
{
  "HomePage": {
    "title": "Hallo Welt!"
  }
}

messages/en.json
{
  "HomePage": {
    "title": "Hello world!"
  }
}


This won't work because the config of next-intl assumes to have [locale] folder at the top. Now if you have folder structure like -[countryCode] / [locale] / <inner_directories> this won't work.

Finally it works please take a look
